# Function to return a multidimensional array of 0s

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

Imagine I had a function called `multi0(Array)` and I wanted it to take an Array as an argument.

If I did `multi0([5])`, it would return an array that looks like

```
[0,0,0,0,0]
```

If I did `multi0([5,3])`, it would return an array that looks like

```
[
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0]
]
```

I attempted this with recursion, but it didn't work.  How do you implement this?

Comment: Please include the code you tried so that we can tell you what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
function multi0(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    var children = arr.slice(1);
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr[0]; i++) {
      result.push(multi0(children));
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ffuH4/

Or the slightly longer but more effective:

```
function multi0(arr) {
  var result = [];
  if (arr.length == 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr[0]; i++) {
      result.push(0);
    }
  } else {
    var children = arr.slice(1);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr[0]; i++) {
      result.push(multi0(children));
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function multi0(a,b) {
    x = new Array;
    for(var i=0;i<a;i++) {
        x[i] = new Array;
        for(var s=0;s<b;s++) {
            x[i][s] = 0;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

check it out here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tTwUG/)